# How to run uninstall.exe using .Net

Tags: .net

I tried lots of things but i can not initiate uninstaller using .net

```
    Dim p As New Process
    Dim uninstallString As String = "C:\WINDOWS\ProCharge Plugin\uninstall.exe" & " /U:C:\Program Files\ProCharge Plugin\irunin.xml"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = uninstallString           
    p.Start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the application name as part of the `Arguments`.

Try the following:

```
Dim p As New Process
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/U:""C:\Program Files\ProCharge Plugin\irunin.xml"""
p.Start("C:\WINDOWS\ProCharge Plugin\uninstall.exe")
```

Where you pass the name of the executable to the `Start` method.

Another alternative is to use the `FileName` property:

```
Dim p As New Process
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\ProCharge Plugin\uninstall.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/U:""C:\Program Files\ProCharge Plugin\irunin.xml"""
p.Start()
```

Check the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) for more information on the various overloads.

Comment: Change your the arguments property like so: "/U:""c:\Program Files\ProCharge Plugin\irunin.xml""". You have to 'escape' the white spaces in the path.